# MySQL Получить строку с вложенным индикатором наличия другой строки в другой таблице

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток!

Мне нужно получить строку "A" из БД и добавить в нее один параметр "like" желательно с bool обозначением есть ли строка по условию из другой таблицы.

Вот я получаю строку "A":

```sql
SELECT posts.*, users.nickname, users.avatar 
FROM posts, users 
WHERE posts.type='prose'
 AND posts.status=4 
 AND posts.deleted=0 
 AND users.id = posts.author 
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

Вот получение параметра like :

```sql
SELECT * FROM likes WHERE user=? AND post=?;
```

Этот запрос я хочу добавить к первому и получить его в виде like: 0 или 1 ... либо же строку из бд.

Более наглядный пример :
есть таблица posts, user, likes

posts:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

user: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

likes: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В каждом запросе мне надо объединить posts и user. (Это я делаю в первом запросе где получаю строку "A").

И если есть параметр в likes равный likes.post = posts.id то добавить его... Хотелось бы вообще получать что-то типо bool 0 или 1 в зависимости от того есть ли такие данные в likes.

в итоге я хочу получить ответ такого типа :

```js
{
 /// все параметры из posts
 nickname: ***
 avatar: ***
 like: 1 or 0
}
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Ну так добавьте likes в источник данных запроса с соответствующими условиями связывания. Внешним, вероятно. Но вообще описание проблемы - слабопонятное. Попробуйте на примере, что ли...

Comment: @Akina Добавил больше информации в вопрос

Comment: Пример нужен конкретный, т.е. `для таких-то данных в post, users, likes должен быть такой-то ответ`. В запросе объединяются посты и их авторы. Не понятно, когда в поле `likes` должно быть 1, а когда 0 в результате. Вы пишете `если есть такие данные в likes`. Какие именно, если есть like для данного поста и даного автора? Т.е. если автор сам свой пост лайкнул? Или что-то другое?

Comment: likes должен быть 1 когда есть хоть 1 запись по условию likes.post = posts.id AND likes.user = ? (к примеру 541919523) или 0 тогда когда таких данных по условию нет в likes

Comment: @Akina, в теории можно запрашивать SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.post = posts.id AND likes.user = ?. Но как добавить это в новый параметр like в ответе

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, CREATE TABLE таблиц, особенно интересуют первичный/уникальные индексы и внешние ключи.

Answer (score 0):

Формально это будет что-то типа

```
SELECT posts.*,
       users.*,
       EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                FROM likes
                WHERE likes.user = posts.author   -- или users.id
                  AND likes.post = posts.id ) like_exists
FROM posts
JOIN users ON users.id = posts.author
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
```